# Greyed out my codes of null checking before invoking a delegate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I write unity codes in VS 2015, which means it's in c#4 and the null condition operator is not available.

Before invoking a delegate, I did a null check. However the codes are greyed out. Does it mean the grey codes are not effective just like comments? If so what should I do to prevent invoking a null delegate?

```
public delegate void PtjAnimCtrlDelegateColiderSetEnabledTo(bool value);
public PjtAnimCtrlDelegateColliderSetEnabledTo colliderSetEnabledToHandler;

public delegate void PjtAnimCtrlDelegate();
public PjtAnimCtrlDelegate explosionAnimationFinishedHandler;
public PjtAnimCtrlDelegate hitTargetHandler;

public void ExplosionAnimationFinished()
{
  //pjtCtrl.ExplosionAnimationFinished();
  explosionAnimationFinishedHandler();
}

public void SetColliderEnabled()
{
  colliderSEtEnabledToHandler(true);
}

public void SetColliderDisabled() 
{
  colliderSetEnabledToHandler(false);
}

public void HitTarget()
{
  // this IF statement is gray in Visual Studio
  if (hitTargetHandler != null)
  { 
    hitTargetHandler();
  }
}
```

Comment: **"which means it's in c#4"** I am not sure about this. Unity is using ~C#3.4  not 4. How did you install Visual Studio?

Comment: @Programmer Download from MS website and installed it, then installed then downloaded unity tools also from MS website and installed it. The VS  reminded me it's C# 4 when I use null condition operator. Whether it's 3.4 or 4, it's definitely not 6.

Comment: I don't think it is installed the right way. Follow the instruction in my answer to install VS.

Comment: It's highly recommended to use Properties not Fields (my bet is that either VS or Reshaper doesn't like public fields as they are not best practices).  Or it may be that VS detects that you never/always set the value so checking for null is ill relevant. Also please post code and not a screenshot (other than the relevant code which is only the if statement).

Comment: Looks like a new feature in VS2015 update 1, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/6606 , it's trying to recommend `Delegate?.Invoke()`

Comment: @ErikPhilips Usually I post codes, but I thought the grey color thing seems not that relevant with codes, and how the grey color looks like is important. Anyway thanks a lot for transform the image into codes.

Answer (score 2):

> Before invoking a delegate, I did a null check. However the codes are greyed out. Does it mean the grey codes are not effective just like comments?

It means that the Visual Studio pre-compiler/design-time-compiler detects the statement is most likely not needed.

> If so what should I do to prevent invoking a null delegate?

Nothing, the compiler will still determine at compile time (and actually at run-time as well) if the statement is needed.

Comment: He still need to check for null on the delete. In Unity, if you don't check for for null on a delegate before invoking it, it will throw an exception if it is null. Unity comes with a VS and VS tool. The OP did not install that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just heard that grey codes in VS will still be compiled. The null check is still effective. So this is not a problem at all.

IDE makes it grey to suggest that there's simpler formats, which is the null condition operator in my case. However it should not give such suggestion here, just ignore it would be fine.